# How to pass a pointer to a structure to the constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

I want to pass the pointer to a structure(variables of this structure is an array with elements that have value x and y) to the constructor. Next I want to assign values x and y of each variable of this structure to the similar variable values of the structure in the class.

```
class Convex_quadrliteral
{
    protected:
    struct VC {
        float x, y;
    } vertice_coordinate[4];

    public:
    Convex_quadrliteral (VC *pointerVC);
};

Convex_quadrliteral::Convex_quadrliteral (VC *pointerVC) {  
    cout << "\nObject is being created" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //variable initialisation
    {   
        vertice_coordinate[i].x = pointerVC[i].x;
        vertice_coordinate[i].y = pointerVC[i].y;
    }

    //object's properties output
    cout << "Properties: " << endl  
         << "A (" << vertice_coordinate[0].x << ", " << vertice_coordinate[0].y << ")" << endl
         << "B (" << vertice_coordinate[1].x << ", " << vertice_coordinate[1].y << ")" << endl
         << "C (" << vertice_coordinate[2].x << ", " << vertice_coordinate[2].y << ")" << endl
         << "D (" << vertice_coordinate[3].x << ", " << vertice_coordinate[3].y << ")" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    struct vertice_coordinate 
    {
        float x, y;
    };

    vertice_coordinate *pointerVC = new vertice_coordinate[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pointerVC[i].x = 2;
        pointerVC[i].y = 2;
    }

    Convex_quadrliteral figure_1(pointerVC);
```

I expect the output:
A(2, 2)
B(2, 2)
C(2, 2)
D(2, 2)

The output is error: no declaration matches 'Convex_quadrliteral::Convex_quadrliteral(Convex_quadrliteral::VC*)'C onvex_quadrliteral::Convex_quadrliteral (VC *pointerVC)

Comment: You should use the exact same struct, and you should pass a `std::vector<VC>`, not a pointer that just magically happens to point to an array of 4 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You re-define your VC struct, and even though the struct looks identical, the compiler will treat them as two different types.  Define one struct and use it in both your class and in main.